# Vector class reimplementation as dynamic array: Memory faults with copy constructor

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, copy-constructor, dynamic-arrays

For a programming lecture I'm trying to reimplement some of C++ standard vector class' functionality in a own vector class. I've looked at several similar classes and implementations now and my implementation is (save for using initializer lists) quite the same and most functions are working as intended so far. I've kept this example intentionally simple to read, to at least lessen the chance for syntax errors.

However, my copy constructor and I suppose my push_back function are causing memory leaks and I can't pinpoint why, even after rewriting the code for them several times and comparing them to similar implementations.

Here is my vector.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std; 

class Vector {

private:
size_t sz;
size_t max_sz;
double* values;
static constexpr size_t min_sz {5};

public:

    //default constructor
    Vector()
    {
        values = new double[min_sz];
        sz = 0;
        max_sz = 5;
    }

    //constructor with submitted variable

    Vector(size_t n)
    {
        if (n < min_sz)
        {
            n = min_sz;
        }
        values = new double[n];
        sz = 0; 
        max_sz = n;

    }

    //copy constructor
    Vector (const Vector &v)
    {   
        max_sz=v.max_sz;
        sz=v.sz;
        values = new double[max_sz];

        for(size_t i=0;i<v.sz;i++)
        {
            values[i]=v.values[i];

        }

       /*
        cout << "[Copy constructor called with params Max_sz:" << max_sz << " and sz: " << sz;
        cout << "\n referenced vector contains: ";
        cout << v;
        cout << " | ";
        cout << "this vector contains: " << *this;
       */

    }

    Vector (std::initializer_list<double> list)
    {


        if(list.size() == 3)
        {
            std::initializer_list<double>::iterator it = list.begin();
            sz = *it++;
            max_sz = *it++;
            if (max_sz < min_sz)
            {
                max_sz = 5;
            }
            values = new double[max_sz];
            values[0] = *it;

        }



    }


    //destructor
    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] values;
    }

    //functions

    size_t size() const
    {
        return sz;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        if (sz < 1) { return true; }

        return false;
    }


    void clear()
    {
        //set number of elements to 0, reserved memory isn't touched but can be overwritten by new assignments now

    sz = 0;

    }

    void reserve(size_t n)
    {
        if (n > max_sz)
        {
            double* tmp = new double[n];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = values[i];
            }  

        delete [] values;
        values = tmp;

        }


    }


    void shrink_to_fit()
    {
        if (sz != max_sz)
        {
            double* tmp = new double[sz];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = values[i];
            }

            delete [] values;
            values = tmp;
        }
    } 

    void push_back(double x)
    {
        //check for space, if not enough space is allocated, allocate more

        if (sz+1 >= max_sz)
        {
            double* tmp = new double[max_sz*2];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = values[i];
            }

        delete [] values;
        values = tmp;
        max_sz = max_sz*2;

        }

        //then or otherwise, add the new element

        values[sz] = x;
        sz++;



    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        //remove last element in vector, throw exception if vector is empty

        if (sz == 0)
        {


        }
        else
        {
            //create new vector in memory with space for one element less

            sz--;

            double* tmp = new double[sz];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = values[i];
            }

            delete [] values;
            values = tmp;

        }




    }



    double& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return values[index];
    }

    const double& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return values[index];
    }

    size_t capacity() const
    {
        return max_sz;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Vector& v)
    {
        out << "[";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < v.sz; i++)
        {
            out << v.values[i];
            if (i+1 < v.sz)
            {
                out << ",";
            }

        }

        out << "]";

        return out; 
    }


};
```

Here is a test case for causing the memory fault:

```
int main(){

  Vector y;
  cout << y << endl;
  {
    Vector x(0);
    for(double i{0};i<1;i+=0.1)
      x.push_back(i);
    cout << x << endl;
    x.pop_back();
    cout << x << endl;
    x.shrink_to_fit();
    cout << x << endl;
    x.push_back(10);
    const Vector tmp{x};
    const Vector tmp2{tmp};
    y = tmp2;
  }
  cout << y << endl;
  cerr << y << endl;
  Vector x{1,2,3};
  for(size_t i{4};i<10000;++i)
    x.push_back(i);
  cout << "Done" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is a link to the compiler I'm testing it with, with the class and test case already saved:

https://rextester.com/EJFO89500

Can someone give me a hint on where the flaw in my code is?

Comment: You forgot to overload `operator=`, so the assignment `y=tmp2` overwrites the pointer to the memory that was allocated at constructor time without freeing it, thus leaking memory. For more explanation, see [Rule of Three/Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and the question I linked.

Comment: `y = tmp2;` does not call the copy constructor. It uses an assignment operator, which you have not overloaded. Therefore, this is a shallow copy, and its contents would then be deleted at the very next line.

Comment: The `initializer_list` overload is also _very_ sketchy. I presume you still want to clean that up?

Comment: This is not codereview.SE, but consider writing a generic "ensure_capacity" method and calling that instead of duplicating the growing code several times.

Comment: Strange why you are trying to implement initializer lists which is somewhat not necessary for a toy implementation, but failed to implement `operator=` which *is* necessary for the basic functionality of such a class to work correctly.

Comment: Also, removing an element shouldn't cause a reallocation.  You are destroying an entire vector just because the last item is removed.  That is highly inefficient.  Instead you should just be decrementing `sz`.

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable advice - to put it bluntly, I wasn't aware of the rule of three and I had a blind eye and thus had a blind eye on the assignment operator as well; I must have missed them on my lecture notes. Writing one quickly solved the issue! Thank you also for the advise on memory management - I'll review that when I clean the code up now that it's compiling again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is this line:

```
y = tmp2;
```

That line uses the assignment operator, which you failed to implement.  What winds up happening is that the default assignment operator is invoked, which only does a shallow copy.  Thus you have `values` duplicated in two objects, and the destructor will have issues when issuing a `delete[]` on the same value twice.

The easiest way to implement an assignment operator is to use the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
class Vector {
   public:
      Vector& operator=(const Vector& rhs)
      {
         if ( this != &rhs )
         {
            Vector temp(rhs);
            std::swap(temp.sz, sz);
            std::swap(temp.max_sz, max_sz);
            std::swap(temp.values, values);
        }
        return *this;
     }
//...
};
```

Basically, we create a temporary of the passed-in `Vector`, and exchange the current contents with the temporary's contents.  Then the temporary dies off with the old contents.